# Временное хранение данных на PHP

Tags: файлы, php

Делаю что-то типа файлового менеджера на AJAX. Понадобилось удалять файлы (само собой) и я решил, что выкидывать окна о подтверждении — не красиво, так что лучше делать кнопку „вернуть“ после удаления. Но вот проблема: нужно где-то хранить этот самый удаленный файл до обновления страницы (после обновления страницы, понятное дело, кнопка „вернуть“ пропадает, как и пропадает окончательно файл). Конечно, можно сделать временную копию файла и удалить ее потом, при следующем запросе к серверу, но ведь можно зайти с другой вкладки и тогда все сломается.
По той же причине, кажется, не подходят сессии.

Есть какие-нибудь идеи?

Comment: Сделайте кнопку с таймером, аля файл будет удален окончательно через 30 сек, и обратный отсчет, стало 0 - удалить ссылку, удалить файл.... идея думаю понятна?

Comment: Идея понятна, но ведь как-то это реализовано, например, в ВК при удалении записей со стены и подобных. Думаете, там просто большой таймаут?

Comment: Есть, конечно, вариант отлавливать на JS обновление страницы (гуглится, наверное) и отсылать запрос на удаление. Но там наверняка много подводных камней.

Конечно, можно как-нибудь сделать красивое подтверждение и не париться над этим вопросом. Но ведь интересно ответ узнать!

Comment: ctrl+alt+del или рубильник на счетчике не отправят вам сообщения о своем наступлении, так что от таймера никуда не дется.

Comment: Насчет нескольких вкладок: собираетесь как-то оповещать всех об удалении файла в одной из?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В ВК и в любых нагруженных проектах никто не удаляет записи сразу.

У записи есть уникальный номер. Когда вы нажимаете удалить - для записи Н ставится пометка "удалена", а вам AJAXом рисуется кнопка "восстановить". Если вы её нажали, то для записи Н снимается пометка об удалении. Физическое удаление из БД производится когда-нибудь потом.

Насчет вашей задачи. Если позволяет место - сделайте пользователю подарок - Корзину. Для этого в определенную папку кидайте при "удалении" два файла - первый - это собственно сам файл, а второй это его описание - имя файла, полный путь, дата удаления и т.п.

Тогда у вас будет работать кнопка "восстановить", да и сам пользователь будет знать, что в случае чего он может зайти вот сюда и в течении пары часов(суток) вернуть все взад.

Это конечно не явно самое лучшее решение по быстродействию... но файл-менеджеры никогда не были высоконагруженными местами.

В принципе, описания корзины можно держать в БД - и выбирать удобно, и комфортно получать списки на окончательное удаление.

Comment: Подумав, я все-таки решил сделать так, как вы сказали. Только вот думаю, делать через БД или через файл с информацией.
Сделаю хороший интерфейс корзины и тогда все будет отлично + будет кнопка „очистить корзину“ для удаления из нее всех файлов.

Comment: Если есть возможность сделать через БД - то лучше через БД) Не факт, что будет быстрее - но вам точно будет удобнее.

Answer (score 2):

Сессии, корзина и убийство по таймеру сервером.

Файл на удаление перемещаете в папку-корзину; "трогаете", чтобы дата стала "сейчас"; указатель на него и где он был — в сессию. Крон-задача удаляет из папки-корзины всё, что старше суток, скажем.

Сессия по идее, для новых вкладок будет та же, что для первой: идентифицируются по IP, User-Agent'у и куки. Так что после обновления страницы в др. вкладке там корзина покажет новые файлы к восстановлению. По уму, данные корзины можно обновлять по таймеру ajax'ом - тогда даже не нужно дожидаться перезагрузки страницы.